# Как удалить apache в macOs Sierra?

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2, mac, sierra

Добрый день, я пытаюсь поставить nginx + php-fpm по этому руководству https://blog.frd.mn/install-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-os-x-mavericks-using-homebrew/

Все шло нормально до проверки работы nginx. При переходе по адресам http://127.0.0.1 и http://localhost упорно вылазит страница содержащая текст "It works!". Это стандартная страница apache.

Я пробовал его удалить такими способами:

1) `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

2) `sudo killall httpd`

Но ничего не помогает, apache страница до сих пор находится по указанным выше адресам. Сервер nginx запущен и тестирование проходит успешно, но как избавиться от apache?

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам его удалять?! Можете просто остановить его, и он не будет работать и как либо мешать вам.

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

или

```
sudo apachectl -k stop
```